# Removing elements from LinkedHashMap and ListBuffer of ListBuffer, used as vertex attributes into a graph structure

Tags: scala, linkedhashmap, spark-graphx, listbuffer

I have built a graph in Scala using the GraphX API. In my graph, each vertex has a `LinkedHashMap[Int, ListBuffer[ListBuffer[Int]]]` as attribute: every couple (key, value) of the `LinkedHashMap` represents:

- key: id of a node - as `Int`
- value: all the possible paths to reach the node - every path is a `ListBuffer[Int]`, so i have a `ListBuffer` of `ListBuffer[Int]`

(I've used `Pregel` to create the `LinkedHashMap`s). 
So, I want to implement the case of removing a node from the graph. What I have to do is:

1. removing, in each `LinkedHashMap`, the element with the key == id_of_the_node
2. removing, in each `ListBuffer[ListBuffer[Int]]`, the lists (paths) which contain the deleted node (the path will not exist anymore).

Suppose I have the following nodes (I will omit the others):

node 1: `(1,Map(5 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1, 3, 5), ListBuffer(1, 4, 5)), 6 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1, 3, 6)), 3 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1, 3)), 4 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1, 4)), 1 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1))))`

node 2: `(2,Map(5 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2, 1, 3, 5), ListBuffer(2, 1, 4, 5)), 6 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2, 1, 3, 6)), 3 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2, 1, 3)), 4 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2, 1, 4)), 1 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2, 1)), 2 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2))))`

node 3: `(3,Map(5 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(3, 5)), 6 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(3, 6)), 3 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(3))))`

And suppose I want to delete node `3` from `myGraph`. Then, the nodes' attributes should become:

node 1: `(1, Map(5 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1, 4, 5)), 4 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1, 4)), 1 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1))))`

node 2: `(2, Map(5 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2, 1, 4, 5)), 4 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2, 1, 4)), 1 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2, 1)), 2 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2))))`

node 3: `(-1, LinkedHashMap[ListBuffer[ListBuffer[]]]())` - I don't know how to assign an empty `LinkedHashMap[ListBuffer[ListBuffer[Int]]]`.

I've defined the following method:

```
def del(nodeToDelete: Int, vertexMap: collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[Int,ListBuffer[ListBuffer[Int]]]): collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[Int,ListBuffer[ListBuffer[Int]]] = {
      vertexMap.keySet.foreach{ k =>
        if(k == nodeToDelete) vertexMap.remove(k)
      }
      vertexMap
    }
```

But it's just for the point `1` mentioned above (removing the element with the key == id_of_the_node). Plus, if I call it on the vertices of `myGraph` as follows, it doesn't give me the wanted result.

```
myGraph.vertices.map(vertex => vertex._2).map(myMap => del(3,myMap))
```

How to write the method properly (implementing both point `1` and `2`)? And how to use it on `myGraph.vertices`? In pseudocode:

```
foreach key k of vertexMap
 if(k == nodeToDelete) vertexMap.remove(k)
 foreach ListBuffer l1
  foreach ListBuffer l2
  if (l2.contains(nodeTodelete)) remove the list
 if(l1 is empty) vertexMap.remove(k)
```

Also, is `LinkedHashMap` the data structure with the best time complexity for the `remove` method?

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have the GraphX Api, I used your code for some, I hope tightly related, definition, like this:

```
val node1 = (1, Map(5 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1, 4, 5)), 4 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1, 4)), 1 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1))))
```

and so on for node2 and 3, which worked in the REPL by just importing ListBuffer. Then I can remove by filtering:

```
node1._2.map (_._2.filter (! _.contains (3))).filter (_.size > 0)
/*
res34: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]]] = 
List(ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1, 4, 5)), 
  ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1)), ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1, 4)))
*/    
scala> node2._2.map (_._2.filter (! _.contains (3))).filter (_.size > 0)
    /*
    res35: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]]] =
 List(
  ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2, 1, 4, 5)), ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2, 1)), 
  ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2)), ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2, 1, 4)))
    */

node3._2.map (lbouter => lbouter._2.filter (lbinner=> ! lbinner.contains (3))).filter (_.size > 0)
res36: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]]] = List()
```

lbouter and lbinner stand for the inner and outer ListBuffers.

Update: Executable example with delete function:

```
import collection.mutable._

def delnode (x: Int, vertexMap: Map [Int, ListBuffer [ListBuffer [Int]]]) = {
    vertexMap.values.map (_.filter (! _.contains (x))).filter (_.size > 0)
}

val anode = (Map (5 -> ListBuffer (ListBuffer (1, 3, 5), ListBuffer (1, 4, 5)), 6 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer (1, 3, 6)), 3 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer (1, 3)), 4 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer (1, 4)), 1 -> ListBuffer (ListBuffer(1))))
val bnode = (Map (5 -> ListBuffer (ListBuffer (2, 1, 3, 5), ListBuffer (2, 1, 4, 5)), 1 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer (2, 1)), 6 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer (2, 1, 3, 6)), 2 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer (2)), 3 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer (2, 1, 3)), 4 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer (2, 1, 4))))
val cnode = (Map (5 -> ListBuffer (ListBuffer (3, 5)), 6 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer (3, 6)), 3 -> ListBuffer(ListBuffer (3))))

delnode (3, bnode) 
/* 
res9:  Iterable[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]]] = 
List(
ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2)), ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2, 1, 4, 5)),
ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2, 1, 4)), ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2, 1)))
```

For multiple nodes, map over them and remove empty results:

```
    List (anode, bnode, cnode).map (n => delnode (3, n)).filter (_.size > 0) 
res12: List[Iterable[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]]]] = List(List(ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1, 4, 5)), ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1, 4)), ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1))), List(ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2)), ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2, 1, 4, 5)), ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2, 1, 4)), ListBuffer(ListBuffer(2, 1))))
```

Comment: The problem is, I don't know how to access to the ListBuffers of the vertices. Once I've done `myGraph.vertices.map(vertexLinked => vertexLinked._2)` to get the LinkedHashMap, I can't do another map to access to the list. I have to generalize the code you wrote to all the vertices, because I have 1000 nodes in my graph.

Comment: Seeing now the edit. It works, but by the way the map function creates a new collection of LinkedHashMaps, it would be perfect if I could modify those that exist on the nodes directly.

Comment: In functional programming, you usually approach the opposite goal: Don't modify, what has been passed to you. Thereby you prevent race conditions.   The list of original nodes in my example is created on the fly and eligible for garbage collection, as soon as the scope is left, where it was constructed, so there shouldn't be a memory hole. If you happen to use a var instead of a val - which is most of the time discouraged, you may replace its target (the source) in the end with the result. Without context, it's hard to tell whether you should do it and how.

Comment: The context: my graph consists on a social network where the nodes are the users and the edges are the reletionships among them. (1) I need to know which user is in connection with which other one, and that's why the hash maps. (2) Social networks are dynamic, and I want the graph to reflect this property, that's why I want to remove a node (corresponding to a user removing its account). (3) Removing a node equals removing it in each hash map as discussed.

Comment: Well, I was more thinking of the context in programming terms, but that is surely too much to ask at SE.

Comment: I did not answered back because I figured out the solution. By the way, can you help me with another code problem? I'm trying to fill an array with the _k_ vertices ids that have the `LinkedHashMap` with the biggest size. The following code should return an array containing the vertex withe the biggest hashmap size, but it doesn't. Where am I wrong?

Comment: `def influence(k: Int): (Array[Int]) = {
      val sizes = myGraph.vertices.sortBy(_._2.size, ascending=false).collect()
      val kset = Array[Int]()
      for(i <- 1 to k){
        kset.+:((sizes(0)._1).hashCode())
      }
      kset
    }

    val seedset = influence(1) `

Comment: @Andrea: You should really ask a new question, so a) you don't be depending on me, having time and finding a good solution and b) laying out code in the comments is no fun and c) voting in comments is restricted. Of course you publish your question and then provide the link to it in the comments here, if you appreciated my answer, and invite me.